# How do I find and display all the directories and subdirectories which contains file1, in descending order of it's size?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, unix

For a list of given files and for a given directory, show for each file name all the subdirectories in which it appears. Show subdirectories in descending order of file size. (A file may have different sizes in different subdirectories). 
For examlpe we have the list of files: file1, file2, file3 and the directory: dir. 
Assume file1 is in dir; in d/dir2 and in dir/dir2/dir3. How do I find and display all the directories and subdirectories which contains  file1, in descending order of it's size?

Comment: The descending order is supposed to be for all files all together or only for filenames? I mean if you have your 3 file names is the whole list supposed to be sorted or you want 3 separate lists sorted?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Agreed, this sounds an awful lot like a cut and paste of a homework assignment, with no effort put into it.

Comment: And how do you define "contains file1"? Is it enough that there is a file *named* file1 or does its content need to match a given example i.e. are you finding duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

-Use this command on your terminal to find files that hold name 'f1' on place '~/directory':

$ find ~/directory -type f -name f1.

-You can add a size condition for by using 'find' command:

---

$ find ~/directory -size +1k -type f -name f1.

this mean the output the same rules have been applied plus that the 'f1' file should be greater than +1k. Note you can use -1k and it mean the output will be less than 1k

---

Comment: This doesn't sort them

Comment: @SaintHax Could you tell me how did you get  that  key-field numbers. I haven't found it in  'sort' manual

Answer (score 0):

The code is

```
find dir1 -name file1 -ls | sort -nk 7
```

find all files named file1 under dir1 (correct path is needed), give a long listing, and sort on key-field 7 (block size) numerically.